# Meteor Js + sms verification

Tags: javascript, api, sms, meteor

I'd like to implement a sms verification and I wonder how I can send sms to a given phone number by using Meteor?

Comment: hmm thanks :), btw i get one worth to try : https://github.com/coxeh/intelliSMS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been able to do this using the [meteor-twilio](https://github.com/andreioprisan/twilio-meteor) package built from the [node library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) (you'd need a Twilio account).  The package exports a global called Twilio that you can use like this:

```
    // server-side code
    ...
    var twilio = Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
    this.unblock(); // make the request asynchronously
    twilio.sendSms({
      to:'+445678984', // any number Twilio can deliver to
      from: '+12125551212', // must be your Twilio account phone number
      body: 'here is your confirmation'
    }, function(err, responseData) { //executed when a response is received from Twilio
      if (!err) {
        // "responseData" is a JavaScript object containing data received from Twilio.
        console.log(responseData.body); // outputs "here is your confirmaton"
    }
    ...
```

This can be done inside a `Meteor.method` call.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to look for a SMS API which you can use, by searching for something like [javascript sms api](https://startpage.com/do/search?q=javascript+sms+api). Then you could for example send a verification code by SMS and prompt the code in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient thread, but for searchers who discover this, take a look at:

https://github.com/DispatchMe/meteor-accounts-sms

or

https://github.com/okland/accounts-phone

They are roughly similar solutions that can use Twilio.

Comment: From [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.